# How to open a windows file from ubuntu subsystem(windows 10 optional update (Oct-2017))

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am new to ubuntu. I recently updated my windows 10 OS and i also installed ubuntu from windows store and I am having trouble finding my C program files from compling it from this ubuntu.exe

Thank You!!